# How to read all data using Revit API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

we are generated client id and secret id. And also we have got access token using Internal Token.

when running the project we can view Revit file which we are uploaded using forge bucket.

Then again are trying to get all elelments (Building,floor,rooms,equipments etc)in Revit model using API.
using this Link:https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET/

we have using API in onDocumentLoadSuccess this event.

we are passing url:https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/metadata
headers :'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token.

In this we are passing urn,access_token parameters also fine.
But we face "Token does not have the privilege for this request" error.(we have already have access token through API.But for the second time we face the error)

How to solve this, please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the different endpoints provided by the Forge services require a specific "scope" that the access token must be generated for. For example, according to the [GET :urn/metadata docs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET), this endpoint requires the the access token to be generated with the "data:read" scope.

Also, note that properties of a design processed by the Model Derivative service are actually obtained by a different endpoint - not using [GET :urn/metadata](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET), but using [GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/).

Comment: You mentioned that the request to https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/metadata is made during the "onDocumentLoadSuccess" event. Does that mean that you are calling this API from the browser? If so, are you sure that you are using the right token? Because typically you should *not* send any access tokens with more privileges (like creating or deleting data) to the browser.

Comment: Initially we are using this for access token (its works fine initially) InternalToken = await Get2LeggedTokenAsync(new Scope[] { Scope.BucketCreate, Scope.BucketRead, Scope.DataRead, Scope.DataCreate }); and again we are passing same token to next API call.

Comment: What I was trying to find out was: are you generating this token on the server side or on the client side? And if it's generated on the server side, how exactly are you passing the token to the client? If you could provide more code snippets to your question, explaining what exactly you're doing, we would be able to help you more.

Comment: Thank you we have got it. we can get all results

Comment: we need to keep only Scope.DataRead when generating token